# Как передать полученное значение из js в переменную $page файла .php

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

Выполнив этот код я получаю значение - номер страницы например (2) Мне нужно передать это значение в переменную($mypages - которая уже есть) файла .php, чтобы оно изменилось и обновило страницу. На данный момент он просто добавляет значение (2) в конце URL (example.com/2) !Мне надо направить это значение (2) в $переменную моего PHP файла! - Но не добавлять к URL страницы!

/*
* simplePagination.js v1.6
* A simple jQuery pagination plugin.
* http://flaviusmatis.github.com/simplePagination.js/
*/

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        var o = $.extend({
            items: 1,
            itemsOnPage: 20,
            pages: 0,
            displayedPages: 5,
            edges: 2,
            currentPage: 0,
            hrefTextPrefix: '',
            hrefTextSuffix: '',
            prevText: 'Prev',
            nextText: 'Next',
            ellipseText: '&hellip;',
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            labelMap: [],
            selectOnClick: true,
            nextAtFront: false,
            invertPageOrder: false,
            useStartEdge : true,
            useEndEdge : true,
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber, event) {
                // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
                // Page number is given as an optional parameter
            },
            onInit: function() {
                // Callback triggered immediately after initialization
            }
        }, options || {});

        var self = this;

        o.pages = o.pages ? o.pages : Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) ? Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) : 1;
        if (o.currentPage)
            o.currentPage = o.currentPage - 1;
        else
            o.currentPage = !o.invertPageOrder ? 0 : o.pages - 1;
        o.halfDisplayed = o.displayedPages / 2;

        this.each(function() {
            self.addClass(o.cssStyle + ' simple-pagination').data('pagination', o);
            methods._draw.call(self);
        });

        o.onInit();

        return this;
    },

    selectPage: function(page) {
        methods._selectPage.call(this, page - 1);
        return this;
    },

    prevPage: function() {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
            if (o.currentPage > 0) {
                methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
            }
        } else {
            if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
                methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    },

    nextPage: function() {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
            if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
                methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
            }
        } else {
            if (o.currentPage > 0) {
                methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    },

    getPagesCount: function() {
        return this.data('pagination').pages;
    },

    getCurrentPage: function () {
        return this.data('pagination').currentPage + 1;
    },

    destroy: function(){
        this.empty();
        return this;
    },

    drawPage: function (page) {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.currentPage = page - 1;
        this.data('pagination', o);
        methods._draw.call(this);
        return this;
    },

    redraw: function(){
        methods._draw.call(this);
        return this;
    },

    disable: function(){
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.disabled = true;
        this.data('pagination', o);
        methods._draw.call(this);
        return this;
    },

    enable: function(){
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.disabled = false;
        this.data('pagination', o);
        methods._draw.call(this);
        return this;
    },

    updateItems: function (newItems) {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.items = newItems;
        o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
        this.data('pagination', o);
        methods._draw.call(this);
    },

    updateItemsOnPage: function (itemsOnPage) {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.itemsOnPage = itemsOnPage;
        o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
        this.data('pagination', o);
        methods._selectPage.call(this, 0);
        return this;
    },

    _draw: function() {
        var o = this.data('pagination'),
            interval = methods._getInterval(o),
            i,
            tagName;

        methods.destroy.call(this);

        tagName = (typeof this.prop === 'function') ? this.prop('tagName') : this.attr('tagName');

        var $panel = tagName === 'UL' ? this : $('<ul></ul>').appendTo(this);

        // Generate Prev link
        if (o.prevText) {
            methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage - 1 : o.currentPage + 1, {text: o.prevText, classes: 'prev'});
        }

        // Generate Next link (if option set for at front)
        if (o.nextText && o.nextAtFront) {
            methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
        }

        // Generate start edges
        if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
            if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
                if(o.useStartEdge) {
                    var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
                    for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }
                if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
                    $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
                if(o.useStartEdge) {
                    var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
                    for (i = o.pages - 1; i >= begin; i--) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }

                if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
                    $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
                }
            }
        }

        // Generate interval links
        if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
            for (i = interval.start; i < interval.end; i++) {
                methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
            }
        } else {
            for (i = interval.end - 1; i >= interval.start; i--) {
                methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
            }
        }

        // Generate end edges
        if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
            if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
                if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
                    $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
                }
                if(o.useEndEdge) {
                    var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
                    for (i = begin; i < o.pages; i++) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
                if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
                    $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
                } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
                    methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
                }

                if(o.useEndEdge) {
                    var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
                    for (i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Generate Next link (unless option is set for at front)
        if (o.nextText && !o.nextAtFront) {
            methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
        }
    },

    _getPages: function(o) {
        var pages = Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage);
        return pages || 1;
    },

    _getInterval: function(o) {
        return {
            start: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.max(Math.min(o.currentPage - o.halfDisplayed, (o.pages - o.displayedPages)), 0) : 0),
            end: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.min(o.currentPage + o.halfDisplayed, o.pages) : Math.min(o.displayedPages, o.pages))
        };
    },

    _appendItem: function(pageIndex, opts) {
        var self = this, options, $link, o = self.data('pagination'), $linkWrapper = $('<li></li>'), $ul = self.find('ul');

        pageIndex = pageIndex < 0 ? 0 : (pageIndex < o.pages ? pageIndex : o.pages - 1);

        options = {
            text: pageIndex + 1,
            classes: ''
        };

        if (o.labelMap.length && o.labelMap[pageIndex]) {
            options.text = o.labelMap[pageIndex];
        }

        options = $.extend(options, opts || {});

        if (pageIndex == o.currentPage || o.disabled) {
            if (o.disabled) {
                $linkWrapper.addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $linkWrapper.addClass('active');
            }
            $link = $('<span class="current">' + (options.text) + '</span>');
        } else {
            $link = $('<a href="' + o.hrefTextPrefix + (pageIndex + 1) + o.hrefTextSuffix + '" class="page-link">' + (options.text) + '</a>');
            $link.click(function(event){
                return methods._selectPage.call(self, pageIndex, event);
            });
        }

        if (options.classes) {
            $link.addClass(options.classes);
        }

        $linkWrapper.append($link);

        if ($ul.length) {
            $ul.append($linkWrapper);
        } else {
            self.append($linkWrapper);
        }
    },

    _selectPage: function(pageIndex, event) {
        var o = this.data('pagination');
        o.currentPage = pageIndex;
        if (o.selectOnClick) {
            methods._draw.call(this);
        }
        return o.onPageClick(pageIndex + 1, event);
    }

};

$.fn.pagination = function(method) {

    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method] && method.charAt(0) != '_') {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pagination');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Насчет описания не до коцна понял. Насчет данных, Вы можете использовать общий(что присуствует в js и php), например `Cookies`.

Для работы в js достаточно `dokument.cookies`;
Для работы в PHP: `$_COOKIE[]`;

[Подробнее с работой Cookies на JS](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)
[Подробнее с работой Cookies на PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

P.S. Но я бы для этих целей использовать GET-параменты(т.е с помощью ссылки).

Comment: Я получаю значение всех элементов например 300 и код сформировал страницы по 50 выводит их в пагинацию верно 6 и при нажатии на страницу 2, он просто добавляет 2 к урл мне нужно как то изменить в этом js <a href> чтобы он отправлял это значение в файл php и изменял переменную 1 на 2. Но не добавлял к урл